# jQuery reports incorrect element height in Firefox iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, height

Here a short test to demonstrate my problem. I have a page that loads an iframe:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="iframe" src="box.html" style="width: 100px; height: 100px"></iframe>
        <script>
            $('#iframe').bind('load', function () {
                var div = $(this).contents().find('div');
                alert(div.height());
                alert(div.innerHeight());
                alert(div.outerHeight());
                alert(div.outerHeight(true));
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The iframe (box.html) contains a single styled div:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            div {
                height: 50px;
                width: 50px;
                margin: 5px;
                padding: 5px;
                border: 2px solid #00f;
                background-color: #f00;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The four alerts should return 50, 60, 64 and 74, respectively. This works as expected in Safari and Chrome.  In FF 3.5.1, they all return 64. This is wrong.

Does anyone know how I can force FF/jQuery to return the correct values?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var div = $(this).contents().find("html");
```